# How to pass boolean argument to php function?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

When I try to get the value of "sold" and "featured" I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
function list_products($sold = false, $featured = false) {
    global $link;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products product JOIN images image ON product.id = image.product_id WHERE product.main_image = image.id AND product.sold = $sold AND product.featured = $featured") or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

list_products(false, true);
```

Edit: If I try to echo $sold or $featured, they are blank. A 1 or 0 should show.

Comment: Using `false`, a blank argument will be used (try `echo true` and `echo false` to see), in turn causing your SQL to look like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE var = ;`

Comment: Yeah that seems to be what is happening. Can I not use booleans as function arguments?

Comment: How are you "checking" that the variables are "blank"? Have you understood the [*casting rules* for booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)? If you really want to know the contents of a variable, don't `echo` it, `var_dump()` it.

Comment: `var_dump($featured)` returns `bool(false)`

Comment: @Sam can you make a [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) which reproduces the problem ?

Comment: you must not use booleans in parameters! try  `null` or '1','0'. just need after `global $link;` add  `$sold = isset($sold) ? true : false;$featured = isset($featured) ? true : false;` for `list_products(null, 1);`   or   `$sold = ($sold === 1) ? true : false;$featured = ($featured === 1) ? true : false;` for using `list_products(0, 1);` but never use booleans as parameters!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In your case you can give the arguments numeric values when calling the function (you want to use them as numeric in your query anyway).

Try:

```
function list_products($sold = 0, $featured = 0) {
    global $link;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products product JOIN images image ON product.id = image.product_id WHERE product.main_image = image.id AND product.sold = $sold AND product.featured = $featured") or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

list_products(0, 1);
```

Comment: `First of all when PHP parser encounters "false" as an argument when calling a function, it stops reading more arguments.`

I beg to differ.

`<?php

 function test($a = FALSE, $b = FALSE) {
  var_dump($a, $b);
 }
 
 test(FALSE, '123');
`

Comment: This is absolutely false... No pun intended.  But seriously, this is bad information and should never have been accepted as an answer.  See here: http://pastebin.com/GGATGD5X

Answer (score 5):

Casting booleans to strings in PHP for a mysql query is not a good idea - true will become '1' and false will become ''. Use something like `($boolVar ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the MySQL. It seems to be that the variables are not even being passed to the function. The variables are blank for whatever reason.